# How to to display only unique instances of my objects?

Tags: java

I have a table which stores alarms. my query is that i have to display all the alarms which are in the table but alarms that are repeated should be displayed only once. for example

```
table1
-------
alarms
------
A
A
A  
A
B
B
B
C
D
E
------
```

in the above table say A,B,C,D,E are alarms.the alarms which are repeated should be displayed only once for example alarm A is repeated four times but it has to be displayed only once.the desired output is

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

Comment: in a *database* table? if not: what data structure are you using?

Comment: Sounds like you want to group your datasource. No idea what that data source may be.

Comment: Some things need to be clarified: 1) What kind of table? 2) Is filtering until there's only one unique item sufficient? 3) Are the 'alarms' strings, or are they objects?

Answer (score 2):

You will get the distinct alarms

SELECT DISTINCT alarms FROM yourtablename

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what you mean by table in this case, but the data structure you are looking for is a Set. If you add 'A' to a Set that already contains 'A' nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct alarms from table1
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this be tagged as SQL rather than java?

Anyway, you can fetch the results from the table by adding distinct in your statement:

```
select distinct alarms from table1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might either do that using the `distinct`keyword in your SQL query or putting the results in a `LinkedHashSet` in Java, in order to eliminate duplicates and preserve order of insertion.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using distinct if the table is expected to grow to any larger size, it has horrible performance in most DBMS's (poor index usage almost always defaults to full table scan). Group by is better, in that case:

```
select * from table where column in (select column from table group by column)
```

Which can properly optimize the execution provided column is indexed.